# Asymptotics of expression involving floor functions

Tags: inequality, asymptotics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Consider two functions $f_1(n)$ and $f_2(n)$ that grow to infinity at the same speed, say $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f_1(n)}{f_2(n)}=c $$ for some $c>0$. I am studying the squared difference of $f_1$ and $f_2$. Can the squared difference of the floor functions of $f_1$ and $f_2$ be estimated by that of the original functions? In other words, my question is: does there exist some constant $C>0$ such that $$ ( \lfloor f_1(n) \rfloor - \lfloor f_2(n) \rfloor )^2 \leq C (f_1(n) - f_2(n) )^2 $$ for n large enough?
It is obvious that $\lfloor f(n) \rfloor$ grows like $f(n)$, but the difference term makes things more complicated.

Comment: This doesn't hold. If $f_1$ approaches 1 from above and $f_2$ aproaches 1 from below, then the lhs of your inequality is eventually one, while the rhs tends to 0 (for any choice of $C$).

Comment: @Matija but $f_1$ and $f_2$ tend to infinity, not to 1.

Comment: Ah, doesn't matter though. Just take $f_1(n)=n+\varepsilon(n)$ and $f_2(n)=n-\varepsilon(n)$, where $\varepsilon(n)$ tends to 0.

Comment: Ah, I see. You're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This holds if $c\ne1$. If $c=1$, then you need to ensure that the difference goes to infinity. Otherwise, you could have a situation like $f_1(n)=n$, $f_2(n)=n-1/n$.